# Why get I the same numbers with random array using Numba xoroshiro128p?

Tags: python, random, gpu

Why do I get the same numbers with random array using Numba `xoroshiro128p`?
I want the same as with Numpy random array `np.random.rand`.

```
from numba import cuda
from numba.cuda.random import create_xoroshiro128p_states, xoroshiro128p_uniform_float32

import numpy as np

@cuda.jit
def rand_array(rng_states, out):
    thread_id = cuda.grid(1)
    x = xoroshiro128p_uniform_float32(rng_states, thread_id)
    out[thread_id] = x


threads_per_block = 4
blocks = 3 
rng_states = create_xoroshiro128p_states(threads_per_block * blocks, seed=1)
out = np.zeros(threads_per_block * blocks, dtype=np.float32)

rand_array[blocks, threads_per_block](rng_states, out)

rar = np.random.rand(12).reshape(blocks, threads_per_block)

print(out.reshape(blocks,threads_per_block))
print()
print(rar.reshape(blocks,threads_per_block))
```

Every time I run it, I see the same numbers. Yet `np.random.rand` works well.
Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: On this official [Document](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.33.0/cuda/random.html) regarding ```create_xoroshiro128p_states``` - Seed parameter provide starting seed for list of generators. Try using ```time.time``` instead of fixed ```seed=1``` maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending a seed=1, almost certainly means that the random number generator (which after all is just a complex algorithm) starts at exactly the same place in the sequence. and therefore generates the same sequence of random numbers.

The ability to generate the same sequence in an entirely predictable way is incredibly  useful in testing, but in a production setting you want a more unpredictable seed

try :

```
rng_states = create_xoroshiro128p_states(threads_per_block * blocks, seed=time.time())
```

Since the clock time is unpredicatble, the sequence will generate starting at a different point, and the rng_states will be far less predicatble. Obviously you will need to `import time` at the start of your script. Clearly this means that your code will now generate a reandom sequence every times, which will make testing difficult.

Comment: minor note, but the docs for [`create_xoroshiro128p_states`](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/cuda/random.html) has `seed` as taking a `uint64` so [`time.time_ns`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time_ns) might be a better option.  not much entropy there, but better than a constant.  might also be worth printing out the value to make the run reproducible

Comment: Thank you for your response! It was understandable and useful :)